# Why does "off limits" mean "not allowed to enter"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idioms

["Off limits"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+limits)means "not allowed to enter".

However,  ["limit"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+limits) means a point which something is not allowed to enter.
(The Free Dictionary)

I wonder why it uses "off "?

Comment: it's an idiom; it doesn't have to make logical sense

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the term comes from the military.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always understood  the expression as; *(keep) off the limits,*  *don't transpass the limits*, so in this respect I find  the use of *off* quite logical. The expression is quite old and comes from military jargon:

***[Off-limits](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=off-limits):***

> - ***"forbidden," by 1881, U.S. military academies jargon,*** from off (adv.) + limit (n.). Earlier (1857) it was applied to cadets, etc., who were in violation of the limitation on their movement and behaviour. (Etymonline)

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off-limits&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20-%20limits%3B%2Cc0)the expression became  popular from the '40s and this appears to be confirmed by the following source:

> - *[OFF LIMITS](http://wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8708) originally meant ‘not to be frequented by military personnel,’ ‘out of bounds.*  ***The term originated in the U.S. military during the late 1940s when Japan and Germany were still occupied by U.S. troops.***  In the interest of maintaining amicable relations as well for safety and reasons of discipline, certain portions of town or particular establishments were declared ‘off limits’ and were not to be frequented by military personnel.
> - ***The expression caught on and began to be used in reference to any establishment or area not to be entered or patronized by a designated classes (e.g. students, underage folks, athletes in training, . . .).***  It also came to be used figuratively to refer to anything that was a forbidden area (e.g. topics, people, organizations, etc.)
> - *[quote] 1952 “Over the door an official army notice barked in iron-mouthed print: Strictly OFF LIMITS.”—‘Korean Reporter’ by R. Cutforth, xv. page 137.*  (wordwizard.com)

Answer (score 2):

"A point which something isn't allowed to enter" is far from the only meaning of "limit". The meaning "boundary" (used with the plural, "limits"), is more appropriate here. Something that is *within* the limits is okay; the opposite, something that's off-limits, is forbidden. Why "off" rather than any other preposition? I have no explanation there, prepositions are funny.